# LWC Mass Editing Opportunity and Opportunity Lines

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a requirement to build a LWC to mass edit opportunity and opportunity lines which provide:

1. inline edit
2. mass update
3. save
4. pagination

I tried for each opportunity using accordion and 2 lightning data table (1 for opportunity, 1 for opportunity lines), so I have 2 sets of save/cancel buttons for each lightning table. But the requirement is 1 'Save' for the whole page ( list of opportunities(and its lines) ), how to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384523/edit) your question to add what code you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).